# Countable union of closed subsets of $(n,n+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

We were given the following theorem and proof in a lecture. I don't quite understand portions of it and would like some help.

> > **Theorem.**  For each $n \in \mathbb Z$, let $F_n$ be a closed subset of $(n,n+1)$. Then $F= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb Z}F_n$ is closed.
> >     ***Proof.*** Any convergent sequence from $F$ must eventually lie in the interval $(n-1,n+1)$ so all but finitely many terms lie in $F_{n-1}\cup F_n$ for some $n$. Since $F_{n+1} \cup F_n$
> >      is closed, the limit must be in one of the two and so the limit is back in $F$. Thus, $F$ is closed

The following line is the one I don't understand completely.

> Any convergent sequence from $F$ must eventually lie in the interval $(n-1,n+1)$

How was the specific interval obtained? What property of convergence sequence is my lecture using? Are they using "Cauchyness"?

Comment: I think you mean interval $(n-1,n+1),$ not interval of length ...$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Fixed. Thanks

Comment: There’s another occurrence still

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x_m)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ converges, let $l$ be its limit. Take some integer $n$ such that $l\in(n-1,n+1)$ and take some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)\subset(n-1,n+1)$. Then, if $m$ is large enough, $$x_m\in(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)\subset(n-1,n+1).$$

Comment: Does that only work because $(n,n+1)$ is open?

Comment: although it is confusing to take the $n$ for the sequence index __and__ the interval.

Comment: @MichaelCook No. Because $(n-1,n+1)$ is open.

Comment: @PinkPanther Quite right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So the Archimedean property and the definition of convergence, that is? Thank you so much.

Comment: @MichaelCook Yes, that was all that I needed.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Plus Well-ordering?

Comment: @MichaelCook And that too…

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Won't $n$ have to be a positive integer?

Comment: @MichaelCook No.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Why not? Sorry, the exceptionally late comment. Isn't Archimedean solely for positive integers?

Comment: If $l\in\mathbb R$, the Archimedean property tells us that there is some $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $l\leqslant m$. In particular, there is some $m\in\mathbb Z$ such that $l\leqslant m$. The set $S$ of all such integers is then non-empty and, besides, it has a lower bound (which is $l$). Let $n=\min S$ (every non-empty set of integers with a lower bound has a minimum). Then $l\in(n-1,n+1)$.